# Example of creating workflows for sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

From where I can get different type of example of creating workflows using the sharepoint designer specifically creating the workflow for sharepoint site with different scenarios.

Please reply....

Regards,
Girish

Comment: This is a similar question to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170218/sharepoint-designer-workflows-tips-and-resources/1492987#1492987](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170218/sharepoint-designer-workflows-tips-and-resources/1492987#1492987)

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://rshelton.com/Tags/Workflow/default.aspx