# What is the best practice to deploy SPD workflow into production?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

What is the best practice to deploy SPD workflow into production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some good information here:

[SharePoint Designer Workflows - tips and resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170218/sharepoint-designer-workflows-tips-and-resources)